# Using Sequel in Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, sequel

I have a unit test in Rails, the model it is testing uses Sequel for our own internal reasons, but the test data is created using factory_girl which seems to wrap the whole test in an activerecord transaction. I can use `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` but was wondering if there was a way to not leave the test datain my db after my test is done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what test library you are using.  For RSpec 1, the following runs each spec example in its own transaction:

```
class Spec::Example::ExampleGroup
  def execute(*args, &block)
    x = nil
    Sequel::Model.db.transaction{x = super(*args, &block); raise Sequel::Error::Rollback}
    x
  end
end
```

For RSpec 2, you can use an around filter to accomplish the same thing.  I'm not sure how to do it in test/unit, you probably need to override Test::Unit::TestCase#run.